# Why does Pandas tz_convert fail to convert UTC to Europe/London timezone for 2038?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The Pandas DatetimeIndex.tz_convert() does not correctly convert UTC time zone time data to Europe/London time zone for 2038. The conversion does work for 2037, so this bug seems related to the [Y2K38 bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/7/2010/03/15/year-2038-problem/) (although weirdly I am running Python in 64-bit and the Y2K38 bug seems to be linked to 32-bit)

Creating a DatetimeIndex in UTC for some random days in June, both for 2037 and 2038:

```
s_2037 = pd.date_range(start='13/06/2037', 
                   end='14/06/2037',freq='H',tz='UTC')[0:3]
s_2037
DatetimeIndex(['2037-06-13 00:00:00+00:00', '2037-06-13 01:00:00+00:00',
               '2037-06-13 02:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='H')

s_2038 = pd.date_range(start='13/06/2038',end='14/06/2038',freq='H',tz='UTC')[0:3]
s_2038
DatetimeIndex(['2038-06-13 00:00:00+00:00', '2038-06-13 01:00:00+00:00',
               '2038-06-13 02:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='H')
```

Converting this to Europe/London time zone (i.e. London clock time) for 2037. We see the impact of daylight saving time (DST): all times are correctly shifted forward by one hour.

```
s_2037.tz_convert('Europe/London')
DatetimeIndex(['2037-06-13 01:00:00+01:00', '2037-06-13 02:00:00+01:00',
               '2037-06-13 03:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', freq='H')
```

But not so for 2038: timezone label gets updated, but the hours are not shifted appropriately!

```
s_2038.tz_convert('Europe/London')
DatetimeIndex(['2038-06-13 00:00:00+00:00', '2038-06-13 01:00:00+00:00',
               '2038-06-13 02:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', freq='H')
```

Comment: The bit width of your Python interpreter is by and large irrelevant. If the data type you are using will overflow, you need to use a bigger data type.

Comment: I'm guessing the "you" here is somewhere in the internals of Pandas, though. The 64-bit uint which I guess `datetime64` means should be fine for another 500 years.

Comment: no solution, but a workaround (using unixtimestamp integer index instead of DatetimeIndex) with working timezone conversion even after 2038 - probably it helps someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76326094/2738240