# pytz issue : tz_convert() does not give correct (summer) time in the future

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am concerned about a weird behavior of pytz, using `tz_convert()` for dates in the future.

More precisely, given a UTC timestamp: `'2046-05-31 22:00:00+00:00'`, converted to "Europe/Paris" timezone:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Index(pd.Series('2046-05-31 22:00:00+00:00'))).tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
```

returns

```
DatetimeIndex(['2046-05-31 23:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)
```

while it should return

```
DatetimeIndex(['2046-06-01 00:00:00+02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)
```

pytz interprets June 2046 in Paris as a Central European Time (+01) instead of Central European Summer Time (+02).
For instance, trying the above with `'2026-05-31 22:00:00+00:00'` returns CEST time.
It seems the issue is that pytz does not know the dates of CEST and CET in the future.

This is problematic when trying to convert localized timestamp to a date at a particular place for instance.

Is that expected, and is there a way to avoid that issue ?

Note: even if pandas is involved, this seems like a pytz issue, as `datetime.fromisoformat('2046-05-31 22:00:00+00:00').astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))`returns CET time and not CEST.

Comment: from the [source code](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/tree/master/tz), it seems `pytz` is still using IANA db 2021c, which is obsolete; the current version is [2021e](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). So I'd agree this could be a pytz issue.

Comment: I took the freedom and [raised an issue](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/70).

Comment: Thanks, I started to dig, but I was unaware of the the precise cause of the problem (nor the right place to post)

Comment: The problem remains how to deal with it in pandas until pytz is updated... things would be easier imho if pandas switched to using zoneinfo already but considering e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654), an update of pytz is the faster path.

Comment: Actually, an equivalent issue was open a year ago at pytz: https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/31 
Looks like it is not linked to the IANA update, but rather to the fact pytz only reads the old IANA timezone database format (32 bits) which has a Y2038 bug (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).
(the issue I mention only appears after 2038)

Comment: Given that #31 is still open, the problem seems even worse ...

Comment: `pytz` was updated the other day (now v2022.1). 2k38 bug still prevails though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with pytz and future dates after 2038 (2040 in my case). For initializing, this worked for me. Maybe you can adapt it somehow, or somebody else knows how to convert time strings using ZoneInfo.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# from year, month, day, hour, second
dt = datetime(2040, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))

# from unixtimestamp
dt2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(2411416800, ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))

# both return
# datetime.datetime(2040, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
```

**EDIT:**
I also tried to convert to get a correct DatetimeIndex as asked in your question, however, it seems not possible...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

time_string_input = '2046-05-31 22:00:00+00:00'

# pytz conversion doesn't work
datetime_index_1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Index(pd.Series(time_string_input))).tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
# DatetimeIndex(['2046-05-31 23:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)


# Alternative: convert with datetime + ZoneInfo
str_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"

unixtimestamp_2 = datetime.strptime(time_string_input, str_format).timestamp()
# 2411416800.0

datetime_2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtimestamp_2, ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))
# datetime.datetime(2046, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))

time_string_2 = datetime_2.strftime(str_format)
# '2046-06-01 00:00:00+0200'

time_string_2_with_tz_colon = time_string_2[:-2] + ":" + time_string_2[-2:]
# '2046-06-01 00:00:00+02:00'

datetime_index_fixed_2 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Index(pd.Series(time_string_2_with_tz_colon)))
# DatetimeIndex(['2046-06-01 00:00:00+02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]', freq=None)

datetime_index_2 = datetime_index_fixed_2.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
# DatetimeIndex(['2046-05-31 23:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)
```

So while you can get

```
DatetimeIndex(['2046-06-01 00:00:00+02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]', freq=None)
```

with a fixed offset, you can't get it in the format

```
DatetimeIndex(['2046-06-01 00:00:00+02:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)
```

as desired...

I would suggest to use unixtimestamps in your code (e.g., in your pandas dataframe index) and only use timezones when data goes in or out of your program.

P.S.: And in case anyone has 2K38 related issues when plotting the data frames with matplotlib (even if the timestamps are correct), maybe this helps: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17538#issuecomment-1562663533