# Python Time Zone issue with pytz module

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have written a code to deal with datetime but it is giving inconsistent results.:

```
def date_time_conversion(str_dt):
    brussels = pytz.timezone("Europe/Brussels")
    converted_date = datetime.strptime(str_dt, '%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S')
    b = brussels.localize(converted_date)
    return b
```

Whenever I run this code for any date before year 2037 it detects daylight saving time correctly. But Whenever I run it for any year post 2037 it fails to detect the daylight saving times

Example DST DETECTED:

date_time_conversion('2036.08.05 00:00:00')

output : datetime.datetime(2037, 8, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo =<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Brussels' **CEST+2:00:00 DST>**)

date_time_conversion('2036.01.05 00:00:00')

output : datetime.datetime(2037, 8, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo =<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Brussels' **CET+1:00:00 STD>**)

But for 2038 and any date after that :

Example DST NOT DETECTED:

date_time_conversion('2038.08.05 00:00:00')

output : datetime.datetime(2038, 5, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo =<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Brussels' **CET+1:00:00 STD>**)

date_time_conversion('2038.01.05 00:00:00')

output : datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo =<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Brussels' **CET+1:00:00 STD>**)

Its my first time dealing with time zones so please pardon me for any silly logic errors.

Comment: it's a [known issue](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/31) and goes back to how pytz handles the IANA tz database input. Note that pytz is deprecated for a while now; since Python 3.9 you can [use zoneinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).

Comment: potential duplicate of [pytz issue : tz_convert() does not give correct (summer) time in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71471601/10197418)

Comment: Thank You so much for pointing me out in the right direction.